# Current hash rate required for one block

Tags: hashpower

Now, the height of the blockchain is 485531. How much hash power is ideally required to mine block number 500000.

And how much hash rate does a node require to publish a block successfully each hour?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, new blocks are published every 10 minutes on average, not every hour.

There is no 'required' amount of hash power to mine a block. It is all a game of luck, a race against the rest of the network. To mine a valid block roughly once per hour, you would be mining a sixth of the total blocks (~6 blocks mined per hour), so in theory you would need around a sixth of the total hashpower on the bitcoin network. You can see the current network hash rate here:
https://blockchain.info/charts/hash-rate

At the time of this post, that's roughly 1.4 exahashes per second (million terahashes per second).